# Need to validate the 2nd HTTP request based on the first request in python

Tags: http, python-2.7

If I manually try to do it in the browser it works, if I enter the 1 st url followed by the 2nd url.But If i don't enter the 1 st url, the 2 nd url fails.So, programatically I tried to use the 1 st url to gain the cookies and use them in the 2 nd url.But it still gives me http 500 error.Please help me out.

My code so far :

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

cookie_jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

# acquire cookie
url_1 = 'http://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch/simpleSearchResult?queryText=9&ActiveAwards=true'
req = urllib2.Request(url_1)
rsp = urllib2.urlopen(req)

# make 2nd request
url_2 = 'http://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch/ExportResultServlet?exportType=txt'
req = urllib2.Request(url_2)
rsp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
content = rsp.read()

# print result
import re
pat = re.compile('Title:.*')
print pat.search(content).group()
```

Answer (score 0):

I get a 500 error if I enter the first url followed by the second url.  As an alternative, you could try using mechanize to see if you have better luck.  You're missing a beginning quote mark for your first url.

Comment: I have tried with mechanize...it still does not work... Any other way to do it?

Comment: You say that you can do it manually, but I can't do it manually, so we have a communication problem.

Comment: If you enter the 1 st url first in the browser...and then the 2 nd url ....you will get the txt file ....but if you dont enter the 1 st url..then the 2 nd url will not work.....